# How to add methods from a class to an existing object of another class

Tags: ecmascript-6, gulp, babeljs, es6-class, rollupjs

I had one big class that I split in two and load them separately on a page to improve performance. Core part is loaded first synchronously as it contains critical functionality while Extension (non-critical functionality) loads later in the page asynchronously.

I want only one object which contains functionality of both classes. But by the time Extension loads, there's already an object of Core. How do I add functionality from Extension onto the object of Core?

I'm using a Gulp based asset pipeline with

Rollup = to bundle the JS from different files into one file

Babel = to transpile ES6 to ES5

Uglify = to minimize the JS

Here's my directory structure:

```
js
|_ _classes
|   |_ ab.js
|   |_ cd.js
|_ core.js
|_ ext.js
```

I have set the gulp build task to ignore files in "_classes" directory. Rollup parses the "import" statements to bundle the code.

This is what I have in `core.js`

```
//core.js
import AB from './_classes/ab.js';

window.oab = new AB();
```

and this is `ext.js`

```
//ext.js
import CD from './_classes/cd.js';

//let o_cd = new CD();

window.oab.prototype = CD;
```

This is the Core class

```
// file ab.js
class AB {

    constructor() {
        this.car = 'McLaren';
        this.fruit = 'Mango';
    }

    getCar() {
        return this.car;
    }

    getFruit() {
        return this.fruit;
    }

}
```

and this is the Extension class

```
//file cd.js
class CD {

    constructor() {
        this.plane = 'Gulfstream';
    }

    getPlane() {
        return this.plane;
    }

}
```

I'm trying to get this to work:

```
console.log( window.oab.getCar() );  // prints McLaren
console.log( window.oab.getFruit() );  // prints Mango
console.log( window.oab.getPlane() );  // prints Gulfstream
```

Now I can very well import the `AB` class in `CD` class, set `CD` class to extend `AB` and that will give me what I want. But with my current gulp pipeline setup, that would mean that Rollup would bundle a copy of class `AB` with class `CD` as well and class `AB` has already loaded earlier.

Due to Rollup, Babel & Uglify, the class names `AB` & `CD` etc don't persist, so I cannot assume `AB` being available in `CD` for me to extend without importing it first and importing it would mean it being bundled with `CD`.

Comment: "*I want only one object which contains functionality of both classes*" - why`?

Comment: @Bergi Its a legacy system with that specific object being referenced in a lot of places. To prevent the whole thing from breaking, the object & methods available on that object need to remain unchanged while I split the code in multiple parts for better organization and load performance.


Updating existing references would be a huge task, not something feasible at present.

Comment: And do you insist on them becoming `class`es? It looks like `oab` is a global singleton object, so you don't need constructors and prototypes at all - just have your modules add properties to the shared object.

Comment: Yes, class `CD` needs constructor. Eventually existing code will be updated and these two classes would have individual objects, but for now I need to keep it as single object so as not to break the code. I figured out a solution for this problem which I've posted below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied a monkey patch in `ext.js` on `window.oab` and this gives me what I'm looking for.

```
import CD from './_classes/cd.js';

( function() {

    let i;
    let ocd = new CD();
    let ocd_methods = Object.getOwnPropertyNames( ocd.__proto__ ).filter( p => {
        return ( 'function' === typeof ocd.__proto__[ p ] );
    });

    Object.assign( window.oab, ocd );   // this assigns only properties of ocd into window.oab and not the methods

    for ( i in ocd_methods ) {

        let method = ocd_methods[ i ];

        if ( '__proto__' === method || 'constructor' === method ) {
            continue;
        }

        window.oab.__proto__[ method ] = ocd[ method ];

    }

} () );
```

And now this works

```
console.log( window.oab.getCar() );  // prints McLaren
console.log( window.oab.getFruit() );  // prints Mango
console.log( window.oab.getPlane() );  // prints Gulfstream
```